# Java hashCode doesn't work with HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, grid, sparse-matrix, hashcode

I'm attempting to implement a sparse grid using HashMap, however it seems that overriding hashCode() doesn't work quite how I expect. I've boiled down my issue to the following code:

```
public class Main {

private static class Coord {
    int x, y;

    public Coord(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function
            return (((x + y) * (x + y + 1)) / 2) + y;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Coord, String> grid = new HashMap<Coord, String>();
        grid.put(new Coord(0, 0), "A");
        System.out.println(grid.get(new Coord(0, 0)));
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
A
```

However, the output is:

```
null
```

Both the "new Coord(0, 0)" instances should return the same hashCode(), but it doesn't seem to work how I expected. Why doesn't it work as I expect?

Comment: You need to also override equals

Comment: `HashMap` requires both `hashCode` and `equals` to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `HashMap` cannot work on `hashCode` alone.  It relies on `equals` as well.

To explain why, let's consider a `HashMap<String, ?>`.  Supposing for a second that one has infinite memory, one can create an infinite number of keys for this map, but only 4.3 million or so possible hash codes (the number of possible `int`s).  Thus, there will be collisions.  This is why `equals` is required in order to make sure that we're getting the value for the correct key.